# Replacing gradient calculation of loss function in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I would like to replace to gradient function for a loss function in `tensorflow 2.0`.

Say for example I have a loss function which looks like:

```
def loss_function(prediction):
    # do some standard tensorflow things here
    return loss
```

I then apply the gradients using the `tf.GradientTape` method i.e.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

     prediction = model(input)
     loss = loss_function(prediction)

gradients = tf.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

My issue is that I want to change the gradient computation and explicitly calculate it myself for just the `loss_function()` that's currently automatically computed.

I would guess this has something to do with the `@tf.custom_gradient` decorator, but unsure how I can make it work for the loss.

I am using a custom training loop as apposed to sequential/functional api.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually quite straight forward. First define a `@tf.custom_gradient()` function which defined the gradient and pass the loss through it i.e.

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_grad(x):
    def grad(dy, **kwargs):
        # do something with dy here
        return dy 
    return tf.identity(x), grad
```

and pass the loss variable from the original function through this:

```
def loss_function(prediction):
    # calculate the loss
    return custom_grad(loss)
```